# Outlook is ignoring my email's CSS including font-family and background-color

Tags: html, css, outlook

My email looks great in all inboxes except outlook (according to Constant Contact's inbox preview - I'm not sure which version of Outlook it's showing me). It looks as though Outlook is ignoring the vast majority of the styles I declared in my head, including simple ones such as display:block background color, and font-family. Even with an !important. I think the only style it's respecting is the text-decoration. Any thoughts? I've tried inlining the styles, it makes no difference.

```
<style>

    .button {
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: block!important;
        margin: 4px 0;
        background-color: #00a1e1!important;
        color: white!important;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 15px;
    }
    .button::hover {
        background-color: #76bd1d!important;
    }

    .button-donate {
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #f36d2f;
        color: white!important;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }

    .button-donate::hover {
        background-color: #76bd1d;
    }

    .footer {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        line-height: 1;
    }
    .footer a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white!important;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .table-padding {
        padding: 40px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .inner-table {
            width: 100%!important;
        }

        .button {
            padding: 10px 15px;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .table-padding {
            padding: 25px!important;
        }

    }
</style>

<a href="https://xxx/help/donate-money/?donation-amount=1000" class="button"><strong>$1,000</strong> provides meat, dairy, and eggs to a family for one year</a>
```

Comment: is this in the head tag?

Comment: Try html4 with css2 and use `style="..."` in the html tags. Some email clients strip the head part so you have to put inline styling in the html. More info on https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-css-inlining-in-email

Comment: another useful source: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/

Comment: Try using HTML table layouts and set the `bgcolor` attribute instead of CSS.

Comment: Stylesheets are not reliable in Outlook emails. Use inline styles for everything.

Comment: Yes, this is in the head tag, but I tried a version with inline styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Outlook was ignoring styles with an !important by them.

Comment: FYI: It does work when you add a space in between, e.g. `h1 { color: white !important; }`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to email styling. It can be frustrating here. Outlook does in fact ignore a lot of css markup. Here is a guide that helped me a great deal when I first started.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

you can look up the styles you are using to see if it will be ignored before you use it and try to mark up the code a different way.

Comment: Thank you. I can move my markup (such as background-color) to the tables, but how do I get link text to be white, or change the font-family? And I've tried inline styles. It seems like these basic things should be working, is there a different way to declare Outlook styles that I don't know about? Thank you!